# neo4j locking and its consequences to applications

Tags: neo4j

Let's consider the following graph:

```
Steve---KNOWS--->Kent---KNOWS--->Ingrid
                 cool             nice
                   |
                   +----KNOWS--->Burt
                                  nice
```

...and the fact that Steve had a party where Kent's friends thrashed his apartment. For this he forgives Kent, but he wants to mark Ingrid and Burt as jerks. Little does he know that his wife wants to cut off Kent too and as Steve is starting his transaction, she's starting hers. Below follows the sequence of operations on the data set:

1. Steve starts transaction TX1
2. TX1 filters on Steve-KNOWS-Kent'cool'-KNOWS-*. TX1 finds Ingrid, locks Ingrid and changes her personality property to 'jerk'.
3. Meanwhile, Steve's vindictive wife starts transaction TX2 in an adjacent room.
4. TX2 filters on Steve-KNOWS-relationships and name='Kent'. It locks Kent and changes cool to uncool. This update is committed.
5. TX1, still traversing the graph is done with Ingrid and should continue with Burt, or should it???

   - Will TX1 continue and also set Burt to 'jerk' even though Steve-KNOWS-Kent'cool' is no longer TRUE? Steve's wife committed Kent as being uncool.
   - Will a commit of TX1 result in a succesfully committed update of Ingrid's personality property, or will this change also fail due to optimistic locking constraint saying that the result set changed while it was being updated.

Consider default locking and READ COMMITTED isolation level only, please.

I'm not sure I have got my point across and I'm not yet fluent enough in neo4j to test it myself. I think it would be very useful to explain the consequences of the default locking, the optimistic locking approach and the READ COMMITTED, preferrably with a use case, some where in the neo4j user documentation or reference manual.